# Retrieving entities as SelectListItems

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, selectlistitem

Hopefully someone can point out what I'm doing wrong here.  I'm trying to retrieve several objects from a the `DbContext` and convert them into `SelectListItem`s as I retrieve them.  I've read several posts about this and they seem to be doing the same thing I am, but when I run this code it's always just a SelectList of SelectListItems whose names are "System.Web.MVC.SelectListItem" and Id is null.  Here's the code:

```
        var wtf = db.Departments.ToList().Select(m => new SelectListItem
        {
            Text = m.Name,
            Value = m.Id.ToString()
        });

        SelectList dafuq = new SelectList(wtf);

        ViewBag.Departments = dafuq;

        return View(model);
```

No exceptions are thrown or anything.

If I just call

```
var omg = db.Departments.ToList();
```

before that it returns the objects as expected.

Thanks!

Comment: FYI You do not have to call ToList()

Comment: It's my understanding that Linq to SQL doesn't contain the method ToString, so I have to make it linq to objects with ToList to use that method?

Comment: Your naming conventions of variables are too weird!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
var wtf = db.Departments.ToList()
var dafuq = new SelectList(wtf, "Id", "Name");
ViewBag.Departments = dafuq;

return View(model);
```

Comment: Note you don't need the extra overhead of using `.ToList()`. You can use `ViewBag.Departments = new SelectList(db.Departments, "Id", "Name");`

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to a `SelectList`. A `SelectList` created with the 1-parameter constructor converts all of the values in the `IEnumerable` to strings by calling `Convert.ToString()` on them, so that's what you're seeing here.

If you have an `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` (which is what `wtf` is), then you can pass that directly to the DropDownList helpers.

Just use your `wtf` object in your dropdown, and skip the `SelectList`:

```
 ViewBag.Departments = wtf;

 @Html.DropdownListFor(m => m.Something, ViewBag.Departments);
```

And as vorninp pointed out, you don't need to call `.ToList()` before calling `.Select()`. In fact, I would recommend against it.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken this form of constructor expects just enumerable containing items which then converted internally into selectlistitems.

So you can pass departmens and point the properties of text and data field:

```
new SelectList(departments,"Id","Name")
```

Answer (score 0):

Or just-

```
ViewBag.Departments= db.Departments.ToList();
```

And In view-

```
@Html.DropdownListFor(m=>m.Departments,new SelectList(ViewBag.Departments,"ID","DepartmentName"),"Select Dropdown...",htmlAttributes:new{})
```